# Run Macro over set number of rows

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to fill in blanks in rows by copying the prior cells down. That part of the code is working great but it wouldn't stop running when it is done.

I tried to add a dialog box to ask how many cells it to run for but now I have a "Compile error: Next without For'.
If I move the 'Do until' I then I get a 'compile error: Loop without Do'
Here is my current code:

```
Sub MacroFillAreas_A()

    Dim cell As Range, SearchRange As Range
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim K As Long
    
    n = Int(InputBox("Enter last line: "))
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set SearchRange = Columns("A:J").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    
    If Not SearchRange Is Nothing Then
        For Each cell In SearchRange
    Do Until K = n
  
    
            If cell.Row > 1 Then cell = cell.Offset(-1, 0).Value

        Next cell
     Loop
        
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm new to this so any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: I work with Office 365. In this version, `SpecialCells` only returns cells from the used range. So I have the opposite problem - inaccessible cells. What is the Office version you have?

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing the loops correctly. You are using the **Do..Loop** closing statement for the **For Loop**.

For Loop:

```
    For i = 1 To 5
       ' Do Something
    Next i
```

Do Loop:

```
    Do Until i < 5
       ' Do Something
    Loop
```

Change the closing statements for the loops.